# What is libg2c library?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, libraries

I have found the code which links against of 'g2c' library. Why do I need it? Just would like to understand why it might be important and what it does in general.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for curiosity and asking when you didn't know something!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[What is GNU Fortran?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/g77/What-is-GNU-Fortran_003f.html#index-components-of-_0040command_007bg77_007d-40)

> `g77` consists of several components:
>
> - A modified version of the `gcc` command, which also might be installed as the system's `cc` command.  (In many cases, `cc` refers to the system's “native” C compiler, which might be a non-GNU compiler, or an older version of `gcc` considered more stable or that is used to build the operating system kernel.)
> - The `g77` command itself, which also might be installed as the system's `f77` command.
> - The `libg2c` run-time library.  This library contains the machine code needed to support capabilities of the Fortran language that are not directly provided by the machine code generated by the `g77` compilation phase.
>
>   `libg2c` is just the unique name `g77` gives to its version of `libf2c` to distinguish it from any copy of `libf2c` installed from [`f2c`](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) (or versions of `g77` that built `libf2c` under that same name) on the system.

You may think of it as, `libg2c` is to `g77` as `libc` is to `gcc`.

Note that as of the GCC 4.x series, `g77` has been discontinued, replaced by [gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran), which produces programs that do not require an extra `libg2c` runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

"This library contains the machine code needed to support capabilities of the Fortran language that are not directly provided by the machine code generated by the g77 compilation phase."
from this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/g77/What-is-GNU-Fortran_003f.html)

Answer (score 0):

Installing `compat-gcc-34-g77` solves this requirement.
(gcc-34 must be replaced by your gcc version)